# Make NSDateFormatter emit the string "UTC" instead of the string "GMT"?

Tags: objective-c, nsdateformatter, date-formatting

I have the following Objective-C code that attempts to generate a string with the current date/time in UTC:

```
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSTimeZone *utc = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:utc];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss zzz"];
NSString *utcDateString = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:currentDate];
```

This code *almost* generates what I want. The resulting value of `utcDateString` on my system is:

`2019-06-17--22-28-13 GMT`

However, my desired output includes the string "UTC", *not* "GMT", as in:

`2019-06-17--22-28-13 UTC`

Is there a way to get the [NSDateFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdateformatter) to emit the string "UTC" for the `zzz` portion of the date format?  I'd prefer not to have to resort to leaving the "zzz" off of my date format string, and then manually append a "UTC" onto the resulting date string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no date format specifier that returns `UTC`.

Since you are hardcoding the UTC timezone for the formatter, then simply hardcode the string `UTC` in the date format.

Also note that you want `yyyy`, not `YYYY` for the year.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd--HH-mm-ss 'UTC'"];
```

If you need to handle other timezones and want `GMT` to appear as `UTC`, then use `zzz` (as you already are) and use string replacement on the result to convert `GMT` to `UTC`.

One other possible idea to consider is to use some number of `X` for the timezone specifier. This will give the timezone offset as numbers but if the timezone offset is 0, then it results in `Z` (for Zulu).